# How to show exteranal window in qml-based application

Tags: qt, window, qml, external

I have an application that gui is made up with QML. The task is to start an external program (LibreOffice) "inside" my application. It means that when you press the button on the app's face, external program must be shown in the same window as the main program is. And also it can be closed by app's button that is drown under the external window.

The only thing that I could do for the moment is to start lowriter with QProcess using [this](http://www.pezzino.ch/running-external-processes-in-qt/) article. But it is still shown in separate window and I don't know how to make a button that will close lowriter.

If somebody have any thoughts about how to do this, it would be great if you share it.. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to do something like this with just Qt/QML, you'd have to resort to platform-specific hacks. Even then, this sounds like it would be extremely complex to get right.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Finally I had to replace the qml part of application with qwidgets, catch the external windows id with linux tools and embed window with QWindow::fromWinId(id) and QWidget::createWindowContainer(window).